# Performing click event on google map cluster item in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/) . I want to perform click event on a cluster item (marker) without actually clicking it .

When I didn't use clustering rather I use plain `Marker` I used this .

```
marker.showInfoWindow()
```

But in case of clustering , I couldn't find a similar way .

Answer (score 1):

For zoom in and show markers (ungrouping the cluster) in cluster.

```
clusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener(this);
```

For individual marker click listener in cluster.

```
clusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(this);
```